# ImportError: cannot import name splitgophertype - python

Tags: python, osx-lion

So Im using Python for the first time and have ran into an error that Google is not doing a good job in helping me figure out.

Im running OSX Lion 10.7.4, Python 2.7.3, and have the xCode command line tool installed.

I cant seem to get any packages to install. and keep getting the following error:

```
distribute-0.6.26 user$ python setup.py install --prefix=~/.local
Before install bootstrap.
Scanning installed packages
No setuptools distribution found
running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 214, in <module>
        scripts = scripts,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/setuptools/command/install.py", line 73, in run
        self.do_egg_install()
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/setuptools/command/install.py", line 82, in do_egg_install
        easy_install = self.distribution.get_command_class('easy_install')
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/setuptools/dist.py", line 362, in get_command_class
        self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/pkg_resources.py", line 1993, in load
        entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 26, in <module>
        from setuptools.package_index import PackageIndex
      File "/Users/user/distribute-0.6.26/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
        import sys, os.path, re, urlparse, urllib, urllib2, shutil, random, socket, cStringIO
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/urllib2.py", line 110, in <module>

ImportError: cannot import name splitgophertype
```

I dont mind reinstalling Python but I dont know the best way to accomplish that on OSX. Ive tried installing pip so that I can uninstall urllib2 but I cant get it to install.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks
-J

Added the result of dir(urllib)

```
['ContentTooShortError', 'FancyURLopener', 'MAXFTPCACHE', 'URLopener', '__all__',     
'__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', 
'_ftperrors', '_get_proxies', '_get_proxy_settings', '_have_ssl', '_hexdig', '_hextochr', 
'_hostprog', '_is_unicode', '_localhost', '_noheaders', '_nportprog', '_passwdprog', 
'_portprog', '_queryprog', '_safe_map', '_safe_quoters', '_tagprog', '_thishost', 
'_typeprog', '_urlopener', '_userprog', '_valueprog', 'addbase', 'addclosehook', 
'addinfo', 'addinfourl', 'always_safe', 'base64', 'basejoin', 'c', 'ftpcache', 
'ftperrors', 'ftpwrapper', 'getproxies', 'getproxies_environment', 
'getproxies_macosx_sysconf', 'i', 'localhost', 'noheaders', 'os', 'pathname2url', 
'proxy_bypass', 'proxy_bypass_environment', 'proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf', 'quote', 
'quote_plus', 'reporthook', 'socket', 'splitattr', 'splithost', 'splitnport', 
'splitpasswd', 'splitport', 'splitquery', 'splittag', 'splittype', 'splituser', 
'splitvalue', 'ssl', 'string', 'sys', 'test1', 'thishost', 'time', 'toBytes', 'unquote', 
'unquote_plus', 'unwrap', 'url2pathname', 'urlcleanup', 'urlencode', 'urlopen', 'urlretrieve']
```

Comment: Hi. The issue seems to be with `urllib'. Looking briefly at the source of `distribute', it doesn't seem to be using that. Does putting in `import urllib' at Python interpreter work fine? If yes, can you post result of dir(urllib) afterwards?

PS: distribute is at new minor revision, make sure to go and get a new version!